# How you save an Array from TMDB to SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, rest

let's get straight. I want to build an movie app which have popular and kid, when data's liked, it store in SQLite. So in layout favorited, i make 2 layout, popular and kid. To distribute the data, i used clause category : movie and genre_ids : 16 / not. But when i test my app (previously i reinstall it, like suggestion in this site) and liked the movie, in logcat show something like this :

```
    2019-10-11 09:24:05.941 5582-5582/com.example.apkfin5 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting overview=blablabla. backdroppath=/n6bUvigpRFqSwmPp1m2YADdbRBc.jpg release_date=2019-10-02 [genre_ids]=null posterpath=/udDclJoHjfjb8Ekgsd4FDteOkCU.jpg id=475557 title=Joker category=movie
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: favorite.genre_ids (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at com.example.apkfin5.db.FavHelper.insert(FavHelper.java:58)
        at com.example.apkfin5.provider.FavProvider.insert(FavProvider.java:69)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:266)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1603)
        at com.example.apkfin5.ui.activity.DetailFilmActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DetailFilmActivity.java:170)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3608)
```

You can see that the genre_ids is null, and i set my app, when data's null, data will not distribute to SQLite. So why i can't get the genre_ids ?

For support the diagnose, here's my dbHelper :

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "dbmovieapp";
    private static final int DATABASE_VER = 1;
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_FAVORITE = String.format(
            "CREATE TABLE %s" + " (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    " %s NULL)",

            TABLE_FAVORITE,
            DbContract.Columns._ID,
            DbContract.Columns.FAVID,
            DbContract.Columns.BACKDROPPATH,
            DbContract.Columns.POSTERPATH,
            DbContract.Columns.TITLE,
            DbContract.Columns.RELEASE_DATE,
            DbContract.Columns.OVERVIEW,
            DbContract.Columns.CATEGORY,
            DbContract.Columns.GENRE

    );

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_FAVORITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FAVORITE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

my favorite Helper :

```
public class FavHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = TABLE_FAVORITE;
    private static DbHelper dbHelper;
    private static FavHelper INSTANCE;

    private static SQLiteDatabase database;

    public FavHelper(Context context) {dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);}

    public static FavHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {synchronized (SQLiteOpenHelper.class){
            if(INSTANCE == null) {INSTANCE = new FavHelper(context);}
        }}
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();}

    public void close() {dbHelper.close();
    if (database.isOpen())
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor queryById(String id) {
        return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,_ID + " = ?"
        ,new String[]{id}, null, null, null, null);}

    public Cursor query() {
        return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null,null,null,null,null,_ID + " DESC");}

    public long insert(ContentValues contentValues) {return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,contentValues); }

    public int update(String id, ContentValues contentValues) {return database.update(DATABASE_TABLE,contentValues,_ID + " = ?", new String[] {id});}

    public int delete(String id) {return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, _ID + " = ?", new String[]{id});}

    public static ArrayList<Favorite> getFilmFavorite(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<Favorite> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_ID));
            int favId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FAVID));
            String backdrop = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BACKDROPPATH));
            String posterpath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(POSTERPATH));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TITLE));
            String overview = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OVERVIEW));
            String release = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RELEASE_DATE));
            String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CATEGORY));
            List genre = Collections.singletonList(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(String.valueOf(GENRE))));

            if(!genre.equals("16") && category.equals("movie")) {
                arrayList.add(new Favorite(id, favId, title, backdrop, posterpath, overview, release, category, genre));
            }}

        return arrayList;
        }
    public static ArrayList<Favorite> getFilmKidFavorite(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<Favorite> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_ID));
            int favId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FAVID));
            String backdrop = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BACKDROPPATH));
            String posterpath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(POSTERPATH));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TITLE));
            String overview = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OVERVIEW));
            String release = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RELEASE_DATE));
            String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CATEGORY));
            List genre = Collections.singletonList(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(String.valueOf(GENRE))));

            if(genre.equals("16") && category.equals("movie")) {
                arrayList.add(new Favorite(id, favId, title, backdrop, posterpath, overview, release, category, genre));
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

my dbContract :

```
public class DbContract {


    private static String SCHEME = "content";
    public static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.apkfin5";

    public static final class Columns implements BaseColumns {

        public static String TABLE_FAVORITE = "favorite";
        public static String FAVID = "id";
        public static String BACKDROPPATH = "backdroppath";
        public static String POSTERPATH = "posterpath";
        public static String TITLE = "title";
        public static String OVERVIEW = "overview";
        public static String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
        public static String CATEGORY = "category";
        public static List GENRE = Collections.singletonList("genre_ids");

        public static Uri C_URI = new Uri.Builder().scheme(SCHEME).authority(AUTHORITY)
                .appendPath(TABLE_FAVORITE).build();
    }

    public static String getColumnString(Cursor cursor, String column) {return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(column));}

    public static int getColumnInt(Cursor cursor, String column) {return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(column));}

}
```

a half of my detail movie when it's being like and store it in Favorite model :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(cekFav()) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(C_URI + "/" + id);
            getContentResolver().delete(uri,null,null);
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_24dp);
            Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.unFav), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else {
            favorite.setId(Favid);
            favorite.setTitle(tittle);
            favorite.setPosterPath(poster);
            favorite.setBackdropPath(backdrop);
            favorite.setReleasedate(releasedate);
            favorite.setOverView(overView);
            favorite.setGenre(Collections.singletonList(genre));
            favorite.setCategoty("movie");

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(FAVID,Favid);
            contentValues.put(TITLE,tittle);
            contentValues.put(OVERVIEW,overView);
            contentValues.put(BACKDROPPATH,backdrop);
            contentValues.put(RELEASE_DATE,releasedate);
            contentValues.put(POSTERPATH,poster);
            contentValues.put(String.valueOf(GENRE), genre);
            contentValues.put(CATEGORY,"movie");

            if (getContentResolver().insert(C_URI,contentValues) != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this,tittle + " " + getString(R.string.Fav), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
            } else { Toast.makeText(this, tittle + " " + getString(R.string.favError), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }
        sendRefreshBroadcast(getApplicationContext());
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Model of movie to Store data from Api :

```
public class Film {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdrop;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;

    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private float rating;

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overView;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBackdrop() {return backdrop;}

    public void setBackdrop(String backdrop) {this.backdrop = backdrop;}


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public String getOverView() {return overView;}

    public void setOverView(String overView) {this.overView = overView;}
}
```

Then Favorite Model, to storage data when's like :

```
public class Favorite implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private int mId;
    private String backdropPath;
    private String posterPath;
    private String title;
    private String overview;
    private String releasedate;
    private String category;
    private List genre;

    public int getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public int getmId() { return mId;  }

    public void setmId(int mId) { this.mId = mId; }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getOverView() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverView(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleasedate() { return releasedate; }

    public void setReleasedate(String releasedate) { this.releasedate = releasedate; }

    public String getCategory() {return category;}
    public void setCategoty(String categoty) {
        this.category = categoty;
    }

    public List getGenre() {return genre;}
    public void setGenre(List genre) {this.genre = genre;}

    public Favorite() {
    }
    public Favorite(int id, int mId, String title, String backdrop, String posterpath, String overview, String release, String category, List genre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mId = mId;
        this.backdropPath = backdrop;
        this.posterPath = posterpath;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.title = title;
        this.releasedate = release;
        this.category = category;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    protected Favorite(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        mId = in.readInt();
        backdropPath = in.readString();
        posterPath = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
        overview = in.readString();
        releasedate = in.readString();
        category = in.readString();
        if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
            genre = new ArrayList<>();
            in.readList(genre, Parcelable.class.getClassLoader());
        } else {
            genre = null;
        }
    }

    public Favorite(Cursor cursor) {
        this.id = getColumnInt(cursor,_ID);
        this.mId = getColumnInt(cursor,FAVID);
        this.title = getColumnString(cursor,TITLE);
        this.category = getColumnString(cursor,CATEGORY);
        this.posterPath = getColumnString(cursor,POSTERPATH);
        this.overview = getColumnString(cursor, OVERVIEW);
        this.backdropPath = getColumnString(cursor, BACKDROPPATH);
        this.genre = Collections.singletonList(getColumnString(cursor, String.valueOf(GENRE)));
    }

    public static final Creator<Favorite> CREATOR = new Creator<Favorite>() {
        @Override
        public Favorite createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Favorite(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Favorite[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Favorite[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(id);
        parcel.writeInt(mId);
        parcel.writeString(backdropPath);
        parcel.writeString(posterPath);
        parcel.writeString(title);
        parcel.writeString(overview);
        parcel.writeString(releasedate);
        parcel.writeString(category);
        if (genre == null) {
            parcel.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            parcel.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            parcel.writeList(genre);
        }
    }
}
```

### This's my first time assigment to build with two different view from 1 API. So ya, i got a little confused here. Thank for the answer.

i've been realized that i need to deserialized this list : genre_id, so guys, can you tell me how to deserialized "genre_ids": [
        99,
        10402
      ]
is it use Class List, then the value just Public int id ? or i need more id ? cause some genre_ids have more than one int.

Answer (score 0):

So, i try to solve with deserialized, but i didn't understand how to implement with that data to the database.

And the best i can do was make another database for save data when it clicked. Before that, i build another request from the web so i can get data only from kid. Make sure that the other request didn't get data, set the request with "without_genres", i'm using tmdb btw. That need because you don't want duplicate kid's datas from reguler movie and kid show in tab favorite. Furthermore, i used that database to make widget. So you don't want your 2 widget (reguler and kid) have similiar movie kid in both of it.